# How to fix screen orientation to portrait for my whole PhoneGap app

Tags: iphone, android, cordova, screen-orientation

How to configure the Phonegap app to be fixed to only portrait mode, I there any possibility to do it with CSS or JavaScript so that I should be able to get the consistent behaviour across the platforms

I found this useful post [detecting-displays-orientation-change-on-mobile-devices-with-accelerometer-a-platform-indipendent-approach](http://www.daveoncode.com/2008/12/15/detecting-displays-orientation-change-on-mobile-devices-with-accelerometer-a-platform-indipendent-approach-n95-i900-iphone-with-javascript/)

Here it is explained how to detect the orientation, but I need to configure it

Is it possible through CSS3 Media queries?

Answer (score 27, accepted):

To fix your orientation in portrait mode just add the below line in your activity tag in AndroidManifest.xml file:

```
 android:screenOrientation="portrait"
```

or this in the activity class:

```
setRequestedOrientation (ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT);
```

Comment: I dont want to do it for only Android, is there any platform independent approach

Comment: then u must set the orientation logically in your class file.

Comment: Could you please elaborate more about how to do it, Please modify your answer accordingly, Thanks for the response.

Comment: Thanks for the response. I had the same issue and couldn't find it in phonegap docs. Can you point to any docs around this?

Answer (score 12):

Actually you can use config.xml to set it to all devices **if you're using PhoneGap Build**...
Set the propertie: ***orientation*** with possible values **default**, **landscape**, or **portrait**
example:

> < preference name="orientation" value="landscape" />

*please note that default means both landscape and portrait are enabled.

Source:
https://build.phonegap.com/docs/config-xml

Comment: It's true, the documentation says that, but it never worked form me with Android, only the Android manifest configuration.

Comment: I think that's if you're using Phonegap build only which is a separate too?

Comment: doesn't work for me either ... that is the best solution, cause if I change the manifest I'll lose it after build the phonegap app again.

Comment: Used Version Cordova 4.0.0.., I fixed/ placed this line in my cofig.XML file. It's working for Android. App run value = "portrait" or "landscape" Mode Alone. Command Line Method it's working

Answer (score 2):

use this code in your manifest

```
<activity android:name=".DroidGap" 
android:label="@string/app_name"
android:screenOrientation="landscape" >
```

Answer (score 0):

I had to update `<path to phonegap app>/platform/android/AndroidManifest.xml` with `android:screenOrientation="portrait"`. Set to default, landscape, or portrait.

See below for a full example:

```
     <activity android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden|keyboard|screenSize|locale" android:label="@string/app_name" android:name="HelloWorld" android:screenOrientation="portrait" android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Black.NoTitleBar">
        <intent-filter>

            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />

        </intent-filter>

    </activity>
```