# How to prevent a Phonegap application to switch to landscape view

Tags: cordova, app-config, config, landscape, landscape-portrait

This one should be very simple, however it's not. I'm trying to prevent my application from going into landscape view so I've changed the `config.xml` file like this: `<preference name="orientation" value="portrait" />`. Unfortunately, it's not working. Any ideas?

Comment: im doing this in 2019 and     <preference name="Orientation" value="landscape" /> works fine in debug build, "cordova run android" on an old Moto G4 phone plugged into usb

Answer (score 36, accepted):

Ok, so I got it: The reason Phonegap ignored the `<preference name="orientation" value="portrait" />` in the `config.xml` file is because my app was in debug mode. once I created a **release version** it stopped from going to landscape.

Answer (score 9):

Small piece of code and here you go. Try it.

```
<preference name="orientation" value="portrait" />
```

Answer (score 8):

hello you can install this plugin 
https://github.com/gbenvenuti/cordova-plugin-screen-orientation

and add this function on you index.js or one of your first executed js document

```
window.addEventListener("orientationchange", function(){
    screen.lockOrientation('portrait');
});
```

thank u

Comment: Thanks - I just put the `screen.lockOrientation` command in a [platform ready](http://ionicframework.com/docs/api/utility/ionic.Platform/#ready) callback.

Answer (score -3):

For platform android just set prefered orientation in androidManifest.xml like this

```
 <activity
        android:name="com.payoda.Insurance.SplashScreenActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait"
        android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Black.NoTitleBar"
    >
    </activity>
```

For IOS the following link may help you

[Force portrait orientation on iPhone with phonegap](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14873568/force-portrait-orientation-on-iphone-with-phonegap)

Comment: How do I get to the androidManifest.xml file? I've seen this answer before but I couldn't find how to add or edit this file.

Comment: It wil be included in your project structure

Comment: androidManifest.xml is in /platforms/android/

Comment: I don't have this path. I'm building my project at build.phonegap.com with my github repository, is that why I don't have this folder?

Comment: Then you might find this blog useful http://pervasivecode.blogspot.in/2011/11/phonegap-build-editing.html?m=1

Comment: Phonegap usually autogenerates androidmanifest based on your config file..it resides under your res or android folder depending on version you use..but if you are using phonegap site to generate apk you might nt have access to it. The above link will be usefull

Comment: When you buid project via cli..if will fall in your project structure and you can edit it.. but in phonegap build it falls inside your apk

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7482600/how-to-fix-screen-orientation-to-potrait-for-my-whole-phonegap-app here an another link you may or maynot find it usefull

Comment: Ok, so I decompiled my apk and I've opened the `androidManifest.xml`, however, the line : `android:screenOrientation="portrait"` was already there. I tried to add it anyway in a new activity but unfortunately, the recompiled apk cannot be installed on my phone (regardless to the manifest edit, it's something to do with the decompile and recompile process). Anyway, since the orientation definition was already there, I think my problem lies somewhere else.